# nsis NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin not having .nsh file

Tags: plugins, nsis

Recently i have downloaded NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin_1.30.zip from http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin but it does't have .nsh file but has .dll file only.

How to proceed in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not necessary for every plugin to have a `.nsh` file. Just put the `.dll` file into your `$NSISDIR/plugins` folder and you can proceed. It will do the task.

Comment: yes it works.i did not knew  that only .dll file is enough.Thanks for your reply.